# I'm missing the link from database (configuration) to JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jdbc, ejb, persistence

I'm approaching Java EE and I've started reading the Java 6 EE tutorial from Oracle, plus various JSR regarding JPA 2, EJB 3, JDBC 4, etc to try to get the whole picture.

I put together some test code in Eclipse with Maven (something very basic), I wrote a servlet, I written and tried different session beans, and that all works.
But I don't understand how I should go about effectively linking the database instance with the container where my ejb and jpa entities exist.

I'm using Glassfish, so the beans are handled with no external dependency; about JPA I guess I have to choose an implementation, and none comes with Glassfish, right?
I'd choose Hibernate, but I guess the same question holds for EclipseLink.
I want to use a container-managed entity manager, so in my understanding everything should work with annotations and interfaces.

I can write my entities, put together a persistence.xml file, fine; in the documents I mention above I read that an entity manager can be obtainer through DI o JNDI lookup, but I'm missing where I should configure what database I'm using (i.e. the connection url), the username, password and schema name.

Plus, I don't get how I can make it available to the system, so that writing:

```
@Resource
private DataSource ds;
```

will find my provided configuration and work straight away.
I'm using MySql, and I have the driver.

What am I missing? Should I read some other documentation? How do I fill that last block so that I can finally access the database from my ejbs?

Comment: Glassfish comes with EclipseLink.

Comment: @RichardSitze Thank you :-) the Java EE ecosystem is so big that I'm still far from the first clear understanding of all the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The link" is the DataSource configuration. In a Java EE container, typically you will declare a Persistence Unit in `persistence.xml`. EACH PU typically contains a `<jta-data-source>` (for container-managed transactions) element pointing to a JDBC Resource. There are several ways to configure a DataSource:

- Old geezers like me usually do it through the [Admin Console](http://itsolutionsforall.com/datasource_jpa.php).
- Java EE 6 also introduces the [DataSourceDefinition annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.html) and its equivalent `<data-source>` element that can be included in files such as `application.xml`, `web.xml` and `ejb.jar.xml` ([more info](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/datasource_resource_definition_in_java)).
- Third, application servers generally exposes vendor specific ways to configure a DataSource. Glassfish for instance let you do it through [asadmin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html) and it's own `glassfish-resources.xml` descriptor ([more info](http://stuetzpunkt.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/create-jdbc-resources-on-glassfish-4-with-glassfish-resources-xml/)).

The Admin Console and asadmin methods are recommended when you want to deploy the same application to different servers (say, `development` and `production`), each pointing to a different database. The advantage is that `jndi` will abstract the final DataSource, so, each server can hold its own database settings (with the same `jndi` name). The final result is that you don't need to change your application in order to deploy it to a specific server.

The other methods are application scoped, so you get the opposite benefit. Your DataSource will be "fixed" for the application, but you will not have to configure a new DataSource on every server.

Comment: I don't want to use the Admin Console as I may switch the application server later, and I want to learn the most tool-independent possible way to do things; I guess that the `DataSourceDefinition` annotation is what fits the most for me now. Is it possible to configure it all in the source code? I've seen a project (that uses Spring) that reads the jdbc informations (url / schema / etc.) from a text file: can this be done with the Java EE API?

Comment: Yes. `DataSourceDefinition` is what passes for a standard nowadays (while most shops will use some kind of console by the reasons stated above). About programmaticallybuilding the PU, most ORM providers will provide a way to do it ([Hibernate example](http://java-persistence.blogspot.com.br/2008/02/testing-eclipselink-jpa-in-javase.html), [EclipseLink example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/OutsideContainer)), but this is by no means standard API.

Comment: If you want some advice from a seasoned programmer, while I'm grateful for Java EE standards and the [JVM WORA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) nature (we are better with it!), as soon as you accept the fact that creating a DataSource will be the least of your concerns when switching app servers the better (yes there are standards... But as soon as you move your first real life project from GlassFish to Weblogic or JBoss you will get what I mean).

Comment: Sorry, the correct link for hibernate example is: http://timoponce.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/create-jpa-entitymanager.html. Consoles are not that bad in general (if you learn to use GlassFish console you will have to problem with WebLogic, WebSphere, etc... They are all very similar).

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work, thank you. Is it mandatory that a `@DataSourceDefinition` annotated class be annotated with `@Stateless` or any other EJB-related annotation too?

Answer (score 0):

Since its not working for you, it should be:

```
@Resource(name="YourDB")
```

`YourDB` is the name that you have configured for `jta-data-source` in your *persistence.xml*

If you do not provide any name and type for the `@Resource` annotation, it will infer default from your declaration. Here is more detail about this default [Field Based Injection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncjl/index.html).

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if the former works, it's that I don't understand where I configure the datasource info (url, username, password, ...) that made me ask this question. Moreover, as I read from your answer, the database reference is hardcoded in the persistence.xml: what if I will change the database type? Any chance to be able to set them at runtime or anyway outside the persistence.xml?